# Quran khatm in Ramadan

Tags: reading-quran

If someone starts from Juz 10 in Ramadan, does he/ she need to finish the Quran in Juz 10 or does it mean just complete the last Juz in order to get the Ajr of finishing the Quran in Ramadan.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to complete the recitation of the whole qur'an (from surat al-Fatihah to surat an-Nas) . To perform khatm you don't necessarily need to recite the qur'an in the correct order of the suwar (for example you may recite surat Taha before al-Kahf etc.) . And it is pretty fine to complete the recitation in a different month. So if you started a recitation before Ramadan and reached the 10th Juz' you may go on until you hopefully complete the recitation be it in Ramadan or Shawwal. It is also recommended after a khatm to start a new one.

Comment: JazakALLAHU Khair. So if I started reading the Quran in last month and I was in Juz 10, when Ramadan started. Just for better clarification, if I finish Juz 30 in Ramadan, it will be considered that I khawatem the Quran.

Comment: Should I read up to Juz 10 in order to have the Quran khawatm during Ramadan or just Juz 30 will suffice. I’m still not clear. Please advise.

Comment: As I said a khatm is not related to a month it is related to the content of the qur'an so if you started a recitation before Ramadan and reached Juz' 10 you may go on and complete it if possible in Ramadan. If you want to make a khatm within Ramadan and started from Juz' 11 and have reached by now Juz' 28 you need to recite the 10 first Juz's and 29th and 30th to complete it but in that case you wouldn't have completed the khatm you've started before Ramadan. But it is up to you to start from Juz' 10 and complete the earlier khatm in Ramadan and start a new one in which you may reach Juz' 10 a

Comment: JazakALLAHU Khair.

Comment: JazakALLAHU Khair. I made the niyaa to finish it up to Juz 10 in order to have a full khatm in this Ramadan since I started it from Juz 11. I already finished Juz 30. I’m currently in Juz 7. Hope and pray that I’m in the right path and clear. May ALLAH عز و جل bless you.